# Move_upload_file não funciona

Tags: php, file-upload

Estou desenvolvendo um código para abrir um xml, caso o arquivo não exista, será criado um novo, beleza, o sistema está criando, mas na hora de mover o arquivo para a pasta que ele será armazenado, o move_upload_file não funciona. Nome da pasta onde o arquivo deverá ficar é **xml_msg**. (O caminho está sendo salvo no banco, o problema é em mover o arquivo). (Obs: Se puderem me ajudar, ficarei grato, é meio urgente pro TCC).

códigos:

```
function gerarNomeXML() {
    $novonome = "xml_msg/" . md5(uniqid(time())) . ".xml";
    return $novonome;
}

function lerXML($dom, $conexao, $cpfCli, $cpfTec, $tipo) {
    if ($tipo === 2) {
        $sql = "select caminho_xml as xml from tbl_mensagem where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfCli and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfTec";
    } else {
        $sql = "select caminho_xml as xml from tbl_mensagem where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfTec and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfCli";
    }
    $return = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($return, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    $nomeArquivo = $row["xml"];
    if (!file_exists($nomeArquivo)) {
        $novonome = gerarNomeXML();
        guardarXML($conexao, $novonome, $cpfCli, $cpfTec, $tipo);
        // criando nó principal
        $root = $dom->createElement("mensagens");
        // retirar os espaços em branco
        $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
        // gerar código ??
        $dom->formatOutput = true;
        $_SESSION['nomeXML'] = $novonome;
        return $root;
    } else {
        // carrega o arquivo
        $dom->load($nomeArquivo);
        $_SESSION['nomeXML'] = $nomeArquivo;
        // recupera nó principal
        $root = $dom->documentElement;
        return $root;
    }
}

function guardarXML($conexao, $caminho, $cpfCli, $cpfTec, $tipo) {
    if ($tipo == 2) {
        $sql = "update tbl_mensagem set caminho_xml = '$caminho' where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfTec and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfCli";
    } else {
        $sql = "update tbl_mensagem set caminho_xml = '$caminho' where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfCli and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfTec";
    }
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$caminho]['error'], $caminho);

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
    return $resultado;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

O seu `$caminho` já está com o nome completo do arquivo e o diretório que ele deverá estar, só que se ele não existe ele não está lá, você quer colocar ele lá.

Então, tente usar `$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` esse será o arquivo que você enviou.

Ao invés disso:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$caminho]['error'], $caminho);
```

Tente isso:

```
$dir = "xml_msg";
$nome = $dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.md5(uniqid(time())) . ".xml";
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $nome);
```

`$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]` terá o arquivo que você enviou e `$nome` o caminho que você quer que ele seja salvo.

Acredito que seja isso, também certifique de que seu script tem permissão para escrita, bem como o seu diretório alvo.

Aqui está um código de exemplo:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_erros',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file"/>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
<?php
$file = "";
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]==="POST"){
    $file  = isset($_FILES["file"])?$_FILES["file"]:"";
}
$dir ="xml_msg";

if(!is_dir($dir)){
   mkdir($dir);
    echo "Pasra criada com sucesso";
}

if (!empty($file)) {
move_uploaded_file($file["tmp_name"],$dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file["name"]);
}
```

Comment: Eu atualizei o gerarNome, porém deu o erro:  **Undefined index: file**. Gerar nome att:  function gerarNomeXML() {
    $dir = "xml_msg";
    $novonome = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(uniqid(time())) . ".xml";
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $novonome);
    return $novonome;
}

Comment: Coloquei um código de exemplo, testa. Espero que ajude

Comment: Vou tentar adaptar o meu código com esse que você passou, mas uma dúvida, será que não está movendo o arquivo porque eu estou criando um em vez de upar? Tipo, no seu código o arquivo está sendo upado pelo usuário, no meu o arquivo deve ser criado caso não exista em vez de ser upado..

Comment: A função `move_uploaded_file` faz o que sugere: move um arquivo que já subiu para o server. Então o seu primeiro argumento deve ser um arquivo válido e que exista. No seu código, esse primeiro argumento tem o nome do arquivo que você quer criar, mas ele ainda não existe. Resumindo: o que você tem que fazer é pegar o arquivo que você enviou e na hora de criar o arquivo (com o move_uploaded_file) move para um diretório e cria ele com um nome diferente, no caso, o que vem da função geraNome(). Algo assim...

Comment: Obrigado por toda ajuda, mas acabei percebendo uma coisa, em lerXML, caso o xml não exista, depois de criar ele não é salvo, então dei um **$dom->save($novonome)**, daí ele já salva dentro da pasta.